# Strict differentiability of a functional

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives

Define the functional $I:L^2(\Omega) \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$I(u) = \int_\Omega |u|$$
I want to know if $I$ is strictly differentiable. I.e, does the limit
$$\lim_{u \to \bar u,\\ v \to \bar u}\frac{I(u)-I(v)-I'(\bar u)(u-v)}{\lVert u-v\rVert }=0$$
for some continuous linear $I'(\bar u):L^2(\Omega) \to \mathbb{R}$. I guess it is not true since the derivative without the integrals is not linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is not even differentiable: Consider $\bar u = 0$ and $v = 1$.
Then,
$$\lim_{t \searrow 0} \frac{I(\bar u + t v)-I(\bar u)}{t} = |\Omega|,$$
and
$$\lim_{t \searrow 0} \frac{I(\bar u - t v)-I(\bar u)}{t} = |\Omega|.$$
Hence, the directional derivative in direction $v$ is equal the directional derivative in direction $-v$.